# Deploy using fabric8 without maven

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fabric8

I'm using fabric8 maven plugin in order to deploy my spring boot services on kubernetes.

Nevertheless, I'd like to deploy other kind of services, like postgresql, hashicorp vault, so on so forth.

So I've my `configmap.yaml`, `deploymentconfig.yaml`, `service.yaml` and `route.yaml` in order to deploy hashicorp vault, so they are not maven projects.

I think that's not mandatory to mavenize this kind of "projects" in order to be able to deploy them on kubernetes or openshift.

Is there any way to use fabric8 as cli or another idea in order to avoud to mavenize this kind of projects?

I expect I've explained so well.

Comment: No, you don't need Maven to deploy those kind of applications. Maven is only good for Java/JVM based applications. You can use Helm or something similar to deploy Vault etc.

Comment: Thanks! And is there any other tool to deploy angular applications without having to mavenize those ones?

Comment: I would not mavenize any app which is not Java. I am not aware of exact tools but there might be some package management tools in Angular (WIth or without support to build docker). Although fabrick8 folks say they are not Java centric, to me it is very Java centred. More details here: http://fabric8.io/faq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Vishal Biyani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873601/vishal-biyani) says, the best choice for deploying instances of third-party applications is probably helm. There are public charts available with installation instructions for [postresql](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/stable/postgresql) and [vault](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/incubator/vault) and many others at https://hub.kubeapps.com/ (as well as other charts out there in other repos which aren't listed in kubeapps).

Alternatively you can check for examples or instructions for each individual tool that you want to install.